# Apply function to Numpy array on certain indexes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array of arbitrary size and a function `fun()` that takes a vector `[x1,x2,...,xn]` and returns the same vector but squaring each element, ie `[x1**2,x2**2,...,xn**2]`.

I want to apply the function to elements that have indexes that meet certain criteria. For example, I want to apply my function `fun()` to each element whose index is of the form `[0,0],[0,2],...,[2,0],[2,2],...` and so forth (index on which both coordinates are divisible by 2).

I know of using things like `array[array%2 == 0]` to check if the value is divisible by 2, but I don't know how to use conditions to check over the indexes. I thought of using apply_over_axis and checking inside the function if the coordinates meet the requirements, but I think this might be too inefficient. Is there any fast way to do this?

Comment: Something like `x[::2, ::2]`?  No change needed if `x` is 3d.

Comment: @hpaulj So, something around the lines of `x[::2,::2] = fun(x[::2,::2])`? Does `fun()` need to be vectorized?

Comment: ^ yes, but `fun` doesn't need to be vectorized as long as it returns an array of the same shape as `x[::2, ::2]`

Comment: What do you mean by `vectorized`? Does it work wth a 2d array?  Or a 3d array.  We can't help with an unknown blackbox function.  All I'm suggesting is how to select a subset of `x`.  Treat that view as you would any other 2 or 3d array.

Comment: @hpaulj I did some edits to the question, I guess I was being too vague to try and be as general as possible. Apologies.

Comment: `x1 = x[::2,::2]**2`